# Java pass by reference issue with List

Tags: java, list, pass-by-reference

I am creating ArrayList l1 and passing l1 reference to the method foo.
As we know that Java doesn't support Pass-By-Reference but here its giving different results.

See the below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List l1 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(4,6,7,8));
    System.out.println("Printing list before method calling:"+ l1);
    foo(l1);
    System.out.println("Printing list after method calling:"+l1);
}

public static void foo(List l2) {
    l2.add("done"); // adding elements to l2 not l1
    l2.add("blah");
}
```

Output:

```
Printing list before method calling:[4, 6, 7, 8]
Printing list after method calling:[4, 6, 7, 8, done, blah]
```

Comment: What´s your question?

Comment: I am adding elements to l2 in foo method after that i am printing l1 in Main method.Whatever i add to l2 all are able to retrieving in l1.  i want to know  how it works in compiler. this is pass-by-reference.

Comment: In practical terms, you can think of primitives as pass-by-value and objects as pass-by-reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: @SteveChaloner: No, I'd say that's a *really bad idea*. It encourages all kinds of incorrect mental modelling - and would certainly confuse the OP if they later used a language which has *real* pass-by-reference. All it takes is understanding that the value of `l1` is a reference, not an object, and you don't need to bend what "pass by reference" means at all.

Comment: http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: @Anil, is it something you want me to clarify in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As we know that Java doesn't support Pass-By-Reference but here its giving different results.

Apparently you've heard that Java only supports pass-by-value. This is indeed correct. But what you also have to realize is that Java has references, and that these can be passed by value.

In this case a reference to the list *is* passed to the method (although the reference is passed by value).

The method then uses this reference to modify the original list, which is why you see the changes on "the outside" as well.

See [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: In addition, this only applies to non primitive types and non immutable Objects like the `String` class.

Comment: No. Same rules apply to all types of variables.

Comment: But, for example, you wont be able to change the value of an int inside a method given as parameter like he is changing the List in his example, or am i wrong?

Comment: ...just as you won't be able to change the references contained in `l1` either. You have to keep in mind that `l1` contains a reference, and not a list.